# how to load picture to server from local drive

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

hi friends i have a problem how to load a picture to server in microsoft access  vba though i have done some coding but that not working

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate "https://visa.mofa.gov.sa/Omra/addOmraVisa"
IE.Visible = True
Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
IE.Document.all("ApplicationNumber").Value = 65371771
IE.Document.getElementById("EmbbasyCode").Value = "210"
IE.Document.all("CommandName").Click
IE.getElementsByTagName("PersonalPhoto").src = "file:///d:\pic\AE5902663.jpg"
   Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
   Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
   End Sub



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/90g1n.jpg


   <td rowspan="5" class="requestphoto">
                        <img id="image" runat="server" width="150px" height="150px" src='/Omra/GetImage?358485787' />
                        <div class="t-widget t-upload"><div class="t-button t-upload-button"><span>Select...</span><input id="PersonalPhoto" name="PersonalPhoto" type="file" /></div></div>
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
```

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#EmbbasyCode').tDropDownList({data:[{"Text":"","Value":""},{"Text":"Islamabad","Value":"210"},{"Text":"Karachi","Value":"231"}], index:1});
jQuery('#PersonalPhoto').tUpload({multiple:false, showFileList:false, async:{"saveUrl":"/Omra/SaveOmraPersonalPhoto","removeUrl":"/Omra/RemovePersonalPhoto","autoUpload":true}, onSuccess:OnSuccess, onError:OnError, onRemove:OnRemove});
jQuery('#COMING_THROUGH').tDropDownList({data:[{"Text":"By Air","Value":"2"},{"Text":"By Land","Value":"1"},{"Text":"By Sea","Value":"3"},{"Text":"Open","Value":"4"}]});});